# Blocking certain xhr reequests originating inside iframe through chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on chrome extension where I have a requirement to intercept and block certain XHR requestes that are originating inside iframe. I tried below code, but its intercepting only top frame requests

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    () => { 
      console.log('Request will be blocked here, if request is interceped');
      return {cancel: true}
    }, 
    { urls: ['*://*/*'], types: ['main_frame','sub_frame']}, 
    ['blocking']
);
```

Comment: What is the URL of the iframe and the request it makes? P.S. Did you reload the extension after editing?

Comment: @wOxxOm Here is Iframe url - https://ppc-excel.officeapps.live.com/x/_layouts/xlviewerinternal.aspx and one xhr request that originiates from this iframe has this url https://ppc-excel.officeapps.live.com/x/_layouts/MruV2ServiceHandler.ashx

Comment: After removing types: ['main_frame','sub_frame'] from above code it started intercepting requests inside iframe also. An way thanks @wOxxOm

Comment: Ah, indeed `sub_frame` means the request that creates the iframe itself, not its own requests.