# Session rule to match all requests coming from iframes

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I had an extension which was using the [`parentFrameId`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#property-onHeadersReceived-callback-details-parentFrameId) property on `onHeadersReceived` with the `webRequestBlocking` permission to strip specific headers for all the requests coming from the iframes of a tab.

To achieve this, the condition was: `request.tabId === tabId && request.parentFrameId !== -1`.

```js
// Tab ID to instrument.
const tabId = 42

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener((details) => {
  if (details.responseHeaders && details.tabId === tabId && details.parentFrameId !== -1) {
    return {
      responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders.filter( /* filter */ ),
    }
  }
}, {tabId, urls: ['*://*/*']}, [
  'blocking',
  'responseHeaders',
  'extraHeaders',
])
```

But with the new `declarativeNetRequest` API, I can't find a good [`RuleCondition`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#type-RuleCondition) to mimic this behavior.

I tried this:

```js
// Tab ID to instrument.
const tabId = 42

await chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules({
  addRules: [
    {
      id: 1,
      action: {
        responseHeaders: [
          {
            header: 'my-header',
            operation: chrome.declarativeNetRequest.HeaderOperation.REMOVE,
          },
        ],
        type: chrome.declarativeNetRequest.RuleActionType.MODIFY_HEADERS,
      },
      condition: {
        resourceTypes: [chrome.declarativeNetRequest.ResourceType.SUB_FRAME],
        tabIds: [tabId],
      },
    },
  ],
})
```

But as said in the comments of [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69467939/blocking-certain-xhr-reequests-originating-inside-iframe-through-chrome-extensio), "`sub_frame` means *the request that creates the iframe itself*, not *its own requests*".

Do you see any condition that could mimic `parentFrameId !== -1` with the `declarativeNetRequest` API?

Comment: There's no solution in DNR. The only solution is to keep using webRequestBlocking in a force-installed extension via policies or suggest the users to use Chrome-Developer-Mode-Extension-Warning-Patcher to enable webRequestBlocking in MV3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround: use a combination of the non-blocking `webRequest` API and the `declarativeNetRequest` API.

I won't add a snippet, but here's the idea:

- Use `webRequest` to see requests to generate iframes
- When we see such request, add a `declarativeNetRequest` rule to match requests with an initiator matching the URL of the iframe

This way, I can achieve a behavior close enough to `parentFrameId`.